# No information from this crash report:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

I was beta-testing my iPhone App (not through xcode), and the app crashed. I plugged it into itunes to read the crash log, but it provides NO INFORMATION at all.

How can I make sense of this?

```
Incident Identifier: 564EAC45-325E-4D9C-9541-F6B5FB1BFBC1
CrashReporter Key:   0c1bab58dbdb74d55434c5b4426f3a6b519bc608
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         APPNAME [1230]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/9B2D2DD4-4F3A-48CC-8211-F408AD23B64D/APPNAME.app/APPNAME
Identifier:      APPNAME
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-04-20 00:33:23.541 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x9003ce77
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31d2dc98 0x31d2b000 + 11416
1   APPNAME                         0x0004d8ea 0x1000 + 313578
2   Foundation                      0x348c47c6 0x34834000 + 591814
3   CoreFoundation                  0x334baa40 0x33445000 + 481856
4   CoreFoundation                  0x334bcec4 0x33445000 + 491204
5   CoreFoundation                  0x334bd83e 0x33445000 + 493630
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3344debc 0x33445000 + 36540
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3344ddc4 0x33445000 + 36292
8   GraphicsServices                0x33727418 0x33723000 + 17432
9   GraphicsServices                0x337274c4 0x33723000 + 17604
10  UIKit                           0x343b0d62 0x34382000 + 191842
11  UIKit                           0x343ae800 0x34382000 + 182272
12  APPNAME                         0x00002a3e 0x1000 + 6718
13  APPNAME                         0x000029d4 0x1000 + 6612

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x326d1fbc 0x326bf000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3074afb6 0x3074a000 + 4022
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3074bfbe 0x3074a000 + 8126
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3074b57e 0x3074a000 + 5502
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309b058a 0x3097c000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309b0bbc 0x3097c000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x326cec00 0x326bf000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x326ce758 0x326bf000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x334bb2b8 0x33445000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x334bd562 0x33445000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3344debc 0x33445000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3344ddc4 0x33445000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x316a3292 0x3169d000 + 25234
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309af30a 0x3097c000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309b0bb4 0x3097c000 + 215988

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x326cec00 0x326bf000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x326ce758 0x326bf000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x334bb2b8 0x33445000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x334bd562 0x33445000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3344debc 0x33445000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3344ddc4 0x33445000 + 36292
6   Foundation                      0x3485e7f6 0x34834000 + 174070
7   Foundation                      0x34851382 0x34834000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x348c35c6 0x34834000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309af30a 0x3097c000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x309b0bb4 0x3097c000 + 215988

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x326d0c60 0x326bf000 + 72800
1   CoreFoundation                  0x334c08f2 0x33445000 + 506098
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309af30a 0x3097c000 + 209674
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309b0bb4 0x3097c000 + 215988

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x326d13ec 0x326bf000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309b06d8 0x3097c000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x309b0bbc 0x3097c000 + 215996

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x003e7dc0    r1: 0x30d7a116      r2: 0x001c4be0      r3: 0x00000090
    r4: 0x9003ce6f    r5: 0x003de030      r6: 0x30d7a116      r7: 0x2fdfea74
    r8: 0x0016d680    r9: 0x2fdfea20     r10: 0x003cfcb0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x0004d8cd    sp: 0x2fdfea28      lr: 0x0004d8f1      pc: 0x31d2dc98
  cpsr: 0x200f0030
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the error seems to be this

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x9003ce77
Crashed Thread:  0
```

This means in 80% of cases that you tried to send a message to an object that you already released.
Good luck

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is to "symbolicate" the crash log, which makes those hex addresses match up with the source code.  WHen you do a build, there is a .dSYM file also created which does this mapping.  Any time you release a build to the outside world, always keep the dSYM file somewhere associated with the binary so you can symbolicate the logs.

Try here for [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697067/symbolicate-adhoc-iphone-app-crashes) on symbolication.